# nginx 1 domain but takes multi sites in sub folders

Tags: nginx

I have the scenario like this
I got a domain

http://foo.bar/ which pointed to /var/www/html
Inside /var/www/html I got multiple subdomain **(which can be generated more in the future)**

i.e 
http://foo.bar/test1/ 
http://foo.bar/test2/

And in the future I generate test3, so w/o restart, nginx should have http://foo.bar/test3/

How can I configure nginx to do that like apache?

can be something like

```
location /* {
  alias /var/www/html/*; #(* can be test1, test2, test3, test4,.. so on)
  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `root /var/www/html;` - See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: yes I solved that myself. It was b/c my nginx user do not have permission to read inside /var/www/html. What I do is just grant the user to the group.